# Missing fingerprint drivers

Tags: 18.04, fingerprint-reader

I own a Clevo N151ZU laptop. Currently running Ubuntu 18.04.2 - kernel 4.18

lsusb does not detect my fingerprint reader.

I then installed Windows 10 to see if it will detect, and it does.

The driver name is:

```
Synaptic WBDI Fingerprint Reader USB 073
```

I tried installing the latest fprint version but still had no success. Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: Same issue on N151ZU here. Any progress since?

Comment: @PierreB. nothing yet

Comment: Did you [upgrade your firmware](https://fwupd.org/)? Is a [`fprint` supported device](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html)? You'll need the [USB ID](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb-ids.html). Did you try `usb-devices`? `journalctl -xef` show any relevant info?

Answer (score 0):

So far the best effort to support it seems here :

https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90/issues/34

if you have a  06cb:00a8 device